# How to do multiple selects in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tbl, author and posts.

```
+---------------+
|     AUTHOR    |
+---------------+
 id | name

+-----------------+
|     POST        |
+-----------------+
|id |title|content|
```

i want to have the results of `select * from author` and `select * from posts` side by side

```
+------------------------------+
|           RESULT             |
+------------------------------+
id | name | id | title | content
```

how to do that? And how to do that for more than 2 columns without using a FK.

OBS: Im using MYSQL

Comment: is there any relation between the two tables?

Comment: no relation between them

Answer (score 2):

Use join:

```
SELECT columns FROM Author INNER JOIN Result ON Author.id = Result.id;
```

Hopefully the `id` in both tables is the relation.

Comment: in the example there is not FK

Answer (score 2):

As we can see there is no relation between the tables, so one solution could be:

```
select * from author, posts
```

And it'll create a matrix

Comment: this will do a cross join, not two selects side by side

Comment: Yes: because there's no relation between the tables, there's no way to show two tables side by side without creating a matrix because it doesn't make sense: which row of Author will be beside of a Post row without relation? The correct way is creating relation between them ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can select two table comumns like this

`SELECT authoer.id,authoer.name,posts.id,posts.name,posts.title,post.content from author,posts`

if you have relation between two tables your query like this

```
select authoer.id,authoer.name,posts.id,posts.name,posts.title,post.content from author,posts
    where authoer.id=posts.id
```

you also use `JOIN` to

Comment: Yeah, that do the job but there is not two selects just specified columns. Im wondering if there is another less verbose query that obey the syntax of two selects in one query

Comment: I m inclded column name for just your reference

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select a.id, a.name, p.id, p.title, p.content
FROM author a
INNER JOIN post p ON a.id = p.id;
```

The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables.

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS:

```
SELECT A.ID,A.NAME,B.ID,B.TITLE,B.CONTENT
FROM POST A
INNER JOIN AUTHOR B
ON A.ID=B.ID
```